# Python - String concatenation from multiple lists?

Tags: python, string, list, iteration

I need to generate a file, where each line is a concatenation of a sentence (template) and four variables.
Those four variables(their values respectively) have previously been collected in separate lists.
So far I have tried:

```
num = [1,2,3]
fruit = [grape ,banana,pea]
fruits = [grapes, bananas, peas]

with open('result', 'w') as r:
    for n,f,g in num,fruit,fruits: 
        r.writelines("This is string number %d. This is a %s. And I like to eat %s" % (num[n],fruit[f],fruits[g]))
```

...this approach raises :

`TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple`.

I am also failing at "mungling" this together with different lists, i.e. first concat the first and second variable + string with an intermediate list, to reduce "complexity".

Could someone give me a hint at where i'm failing?

Comment: Thanks everyone for the fast and spot on help! I obviously didn't fully grasp the concept of iteration / its limits.

Answer (score 1):

A more idiomatic way to solve the problem would be:

```
template = "This is string number {}. This is a {}. And I like to eat {}\n"
with open('result', 'w') as r:
    for n, f, fs in zip(num, fruit, fruits):
        r.write(template.format(n, f, fs))
```

Notice the following:

- In your code, this snippet: `in num,fruit,fruits` is creating a tuple of three lists; you must use `zip()` for packing together the input lists and simultaneously traversing them
- The `n,f,g` iteration variables in your loop refer to the actual *elements* in the list, not the indexes. That's why this snippet: `num[n],fruit[f],fruits[g]` is raising an error
- The `%` syntax for formatting strings is deprecated and should be avoided, use `format()` instead
- `writelines()` is for writing a list of lines, for writing a single line at the time use `write()` passing a `\n`-terminated string

Comment: Thanks Óscar! The template aproach has been / is novel to me, and raises a KeyError, for the second substitution. But I will definitely look up the docs, esp since it's supposed to become the new standard

Answer (score 1):

For statement in python has the following syntax.

```
for <value> in <iterable>:
   body 

List is a <iterable> data type.
```

For now, it means you can traverse it. I would recommend you read documentation for more informatino about iterables and how to implement them in your classes definitions.

but list,list,list is not. 
you will need to concatenate these lists into one list.

zip(l1,l2,l3) would do it for you as a pattern match.
it would make a list with elements matching with index in a tuple.

you can unmatch it at value

in your case

```
for (n,f,g) in zip(num,fruit,fruits):
```

will do.

Answer (score 0):

`num,fruit,fruits` gives a tuple, which makes `for n,f,g in num,fruit,fruits:` equals:

```
atuple=num,fruit,fruits
for n,f,g in atuple:
    ...
```

so the for-loop unpack `atuple[0]` (namely, `num`) , assign values `num[0], num[1], num[2]` to `n,f,g`, and then `fruit[0], fruit[1], fruit[2]`...  that's why you get the error.

Change `for n,f,g in num,fruit,fruits:` to :

```
for tup in zip(num,fruit,fruits): 
    r.writelines("This is string number %d. 
                  This is a %s. And I like to eat %s" % tup)
```

see [docs for zip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip)

Comment: The user is new to python and needs his mistake explained, not fixed.

Comment: Thanks Zhang! Copied your solution, works like a charm.